# Remove Domain Server

Tags: windows, active-directory, domain

A contract employee added a domain server to our network. When it was caught he had already reformatted the server but did not remove it as a domain server.

How do we remove the server from Active Directory Sites and Services properly?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to do a metadata clean-up:

[How to remove data in Active Directory after an unsuccessful domain controller demotion](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/216498)